# Using the same method but get different result

Tags: django

I use `{extends 'xxx.html'}` to make all templates have the same 'head' and 'tail', there's an user avatar area `{{ avatar }}` in head, but I use the same method to pass this `avatar` in every views, my index.html can't correctly show the avatar, but the other can, so I assume is something wrong with my index views.

Here's the index view:

```
def index(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    all_user = UserInfo.objects.all()
    user = all_user.filter(username=request.user.username)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {
        "icon": user.icon,
        "user": user.username,
    })
```

And here's a part of views which could correctly show the avatar:

```
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
        my_fav = UserFavorite.objects.all()
        my_fav_num = my_fav.filter(user=request.user).count()
        my_posts_num = all_posts.filter(user=request.user).count()
        my_msg = UserMessage.objects.all()
        my_msg_num = my_msg.filter(user=request.user, has_read=False).count()
        all_user = UserInfo.objects.all()
        user = all_user.get(username=request.user.username)
        return render(request, 'community.html', {
            "all_posts": posts,
            "post_num": post_num,
            "animal_kind": animal_kind,
            "post_kind": post_kind,
            "sort": sort,
            "my_fav_num": my_fav_num,
            "my_posts_num": my_posts_num,
            "my_msg_num": my_msg_num,
            "icon": user.icon,
            "user": user.username,
        })
    else:
        my_fav_num = 0
        my_msg_num = 0
        my_posts_num = 0
        return render(request, 'community.html', {
            "all_posts": posts,
            "post_num": post_num,
            "animal_kind": animal_kind,
            "post_kind": post_kind,
            "sort": sort,
            "my_fav_num": my_fav_num,
            "my_posts_num": my_posts_num,
            "my_msg_num": my_msg_num,
        })
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="head_bar" style="z-index: 1;">
<a class="logo" href="{% url 'index' %}">Nostray</a>
<div class="nav_bar">
    <a class="nav" href="{% url 'adopt:market' %}"><span class="roll" id="adopt">领养</span></a>
    <a class="nav" href="{% url 'community:allpost' %}"><span class="roll" id="community">社区</span></a>
    <a class="nav" href=""><span class="roll" id="charity">公益</span></a>
</div>
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <div class="current_user"><a href="">
    <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ icon }}" title="登录状态：{{ user }}" class="curr_icon">
    </a></div>
    {% else %}
        <button class="bar_btn1" onclick="location.href={% url 'login' %}">登录</button>
        <button class="bar_btn2" onclick="location.href={% url 'registe' %}">注册</button>
    {% endif %}
```

can't see why the index can't find the avatar.

Comment: I can't see anywhere in your code where `avatar` is mentioned?

Comment: avatar is the `icon`

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve].

Comment: ok, my bad, thanks for your patience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `index` you have list of user but in you 'correctly show' user is single object and it has the attrs, you need replace

```
user = all_user.filter(username=request.user.username)
```

on

```
user = all_user.get(username=request.user.username)
#                ^^^^
```

Comment: I did what you said but it's still the same, the avatar src is empty on index, but the `user` can pass

Comment: looks ok, i can't find error, try to `print user.icon` in your index before `return` may be it help

Comment: It turns out this function never run, I forgot to change the urls function, my mistake, but thanks for your patience.

Comment: glad to help you )